# weird behavior sudo apt install

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to reinstall **vim**, but I ran into the following issue. Whatever I do, if I'm using, for example, `sudo apt install vim-addon-manager`, I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vim-addon-manager is already the newest version (0.5.10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded.
```

but doing `vim-addon-manager --version` returns

```
Command 'vim-addon-manager' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install vim-addon-manager
```

I had to install **NVIM** because the classical **vim** I could no longer make work.

Can anyone give me a hint about what's going on here?
In principle, I want classical VIM, not anything else, the one you get with `sudo apt install vim`.

Comment: You said you're trying to reinstall `vim`, but your `apt` command is for `vim-addon-manager`. ??

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to force a re-installation:

```
sudo apt reinstall vim-addon-manager
```

(or `sudo apt install --reinstall ...` if your version of `apt` is older than 1.8.0).